# Little mod_rewrite problem

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I have a classifieds website. Each classified is linked like this originally:

```
   mydomain.com/ad.php?ad_id=Bmw_M3_M_tech_113620829
```

What RewriteRule should I use to make this link look like:

```
   mydomain.com/Bmw_M3_M_tech_113620829
```

Also, what do I need to add to my .htaccess file?
This is what I have so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

And I have just enabled mod_rewrite which was disabled at first on my Ubuntu server by using:

```
 a2enmod rewrite
```

Anything else I need to know or do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ad\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ad.php?ad_id=$1 [L]
```

This should rewrite a request to `mydomain.com/Bmw_M3` into `mydomain.com/ad.php?ad_id=Bmw_M3`.

The `RewriteCond` excludes direct requests to `ad.php` from being rewritten. The `RewriteRule` would simply substitutes anything after `mydomain.com/` in place of the `$1`. The `[L]` (last) flag stops the rewriting process so that it won't apply any more rewrites for a request that is rewritten by this rule.

Comment: Daniel, `do you think you could you explain the code in detail?

Comment: @Camran: Updated my answer. Let me know if you need any further clarifications :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the rule itself. Requires regex =)

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) ad.php?ad_id=$1
```

Of course, this regex should be fine tuned based on the ad ID you're passing on - by telling what characters can be in that ad ID and similar. For example, if all ad IDs are ending with and underscore and 9 digits, something like this:

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_]_[0-9]{9}) ad.php?ad_id=$1
```

Oh, also, after enabling mod_rewrite restart apache. Make sure that AllowOverride is not set to None, cause in that case, apache will ignore .htaccess files in directories.

Comment: Robert, I have apache2 On a Ubuntu server, and all AllowOverride directives are in the 000-default file... Should I change all of them to 'AllowOverride All'?

Comment: Yes, that way .htaccess files will be executed.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in the second regex. There's a $ sign missing after the closing bracket: ``RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9_]_[0-9]{9})$ ad.php?ad_id=$1``